# Give a element in a key and get the correspond element on a different key of the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

In a dictionary, I want to give a element in a key and get the correspond element on a different key of the dictionary.

Example: if I give **letter b** i want to get **2**. if i give **letter f**, I want to get **1**

```
d = {'letter': {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}, 'number': {5,2,4,9,3,1}}
```

Imagine I want to have letter b and f

```
listing = ['b','f']
```

```
position= d['letter'].index(listing)

goal = d['number'][position]

print(goal)
```

it shows error 'set' object has no attribute 'index' or when i try different stuff 'set' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `index`, because it tries to check if the `listing` is in there, not each element. You can solve it using list comprehension:

```
d = {'letter': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'number': [5,2,4,9,3,1]}
listing = ['b','f']
position= [d['letter'].index(x) for x in listing]
print(position)
>>> [1, 5]
```

Comment: sorry, i make a mistake in the question. i wanted to an dict inside each key and not a list like this d = {'letter': {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}, 'number': {5,2,4,9,3,1}}

Comment: `{'a','b','c','d','e','f'}` is not a dictionary, it is a `set` (for example, try to evaluate the expression `type({'a','b','c','d','e','f'}` - it will return `set`). Dictionaries are made of key:value pairs. If you want a dictionary, it can't be done without specifying the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, except that `listing` is a `list`, so it in itself doesn't correspond to a value in `d['letter']` - hence the reported error. You could loop through listing and use the same code you wrote:

```
listing = ['b', 'f']
for key in listing:
   position = d['letter'].index(key)
   goal = d['number'][position]
   print(goal)
```

Comment: sorry, i make a mistake in the question. i wanted to an dict inside each key and not a list like this d = {'letter': {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}, 'number': {5,2,4,9,3,1}}

Comment: A dictionary requires key-value pairs - as written, your inner dictionaries won't work. If all you want to do is get a number for a specific letter, you could assign those as key-value pairs: d = {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 9, 'e': 3, 'f' 1}.